# ψ used as diameter, which unit is this?

Tags: datasheet, dimensions

I am designing a PCB footprint for this part: https://www.meanwell.com/productPdf.aspx?i=685

On page 4, the pins diameters are indicated as:  diameter:1ψ and  diameter:2ψ

Also, on the quotes, they are using 2-1ψ and 2-2ψ

I searched the web for answers but could not find anything useful..

What is ψ? Why is it used instead of millimeters?
How can I convert this to metric? How large are the diameters of these pins?

[image]

Comment: I guess they simply mistook the '⌀' for a 'ψ' to denote 'diameter'. The unit should be millimeter still.  "2-1" should be read as 2 times 1mm (as there are two pins).

Comment: The sign appeares in many meanwell documents...  https://www.google.com/search?q=meanwell+%CF%88

Comment: They probably intended to use an upper case *phi*. Which is still wrong, a diameter symbol has the slash at an angle.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a letter  "psi". It is diameter sign. 4 holes with diameter 3.5 millimeter.

Comment: Nope, that is an actual Unicode character ψ in the document.

Comment: Yes, you right. So may be file creator mistake.

Comment: a quick google search shows many meanwell PDFs with the sign making it not likely a mistake... https://www.google.com/search?q=meanwell+%CF%88

Comment: How did you reach the 3.5mm number? Also considering the 4 pins have two different sizes...

Comment: 3.50mm 4 holes. Page 4 in the link,  OP provided. I did not reach but read that. Why Meanwell using that sign is only Meanwtell documents writer knows. I do not insist, only guess.